# Adding a badge to new blog post titles

Tags: recent-posts

I wish to add a small icon/badge left to my blog post titles those are new (maybe 5-7 days ago). I may preferably have a blinking gif image for this. Now, how to execute this?

First I tried with this which I got from a WP forum post.

```
add_filter( 'post_content', 'addBadge2Title' );
function addBadge2Title(){
    $seconds = strtotime( "now" ) - strtotime( get_the_date( "Y/m/d" ) );
    $badge= get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/library/images/new_ribbon.gif';
    if ( $seconds < 10950400 ) {
        echo '<img class="new_ribbon" width="75"  height="75" src="'.$badge.'" >';
    }
}
```

But nothing shows up.

Code resource : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-to-add-a-new-badge-to-title-1?replies=3#post-2499846

Comment: When you take something from _somewhere_, then it's under _some_ license. Please link to the original source. Thanks.

Comment: You can add a icon or image before entry titles using CSS. .single .entry-title:before Please ask on Stackoverflow. Otherwise, you need to filter the title however you will still need CSS.

Comment: to be fair it is probably from the wp.org forums http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-to-add-a-new-badge-to-title-1 but it looks like there was some C&P bug in the way.

Comment: I am sorry for this. I had no intention to demean the original author. Maybe I was in a hurry and did not quote the source. I have updated the thread by the way. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Your code example demonstrates that you do not understand how filters work, you will need to understand the difference between filters and hooks to fully understand any answer given

Answer (score 1):

You want to edit the `title`, and not the `content`.

Check this for [`filters`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) you want to use.

If you want to edit your **title** you should [`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) to it and modify it([`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title)). Like so:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'addBadge2Title');
function addBadge2Title($title)
{
    $seconds = strtotime("now") - strtotime(get_the_date("Y/m/d"));
    $badge = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/images/new_ribbon.gif';
    if ($seconds < 10950400) {
        $title = '<img class="new_ribbon" width="75"  height="75" src="' . $badge . '" >' . $title;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

## Edit: use badges only for specific categories

If you want to use this code for specific categories you have a few options

1. First remove `add_filter('the_title', 'addBadge2Title');` and keep only the `function` declaration in `functiosn.php` and in the [`archive-{$category-slug}.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display) file add and remove the filter like so

   ```
   if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post()

       add_filter('the_title', 'addBadge2Title');
       the_title();
       remove_filter('the_title', 'addBadge2Title');

   endwhile; endif;
   ```
2. Check if the current post has the category you want the title to be displayed with badges. Modify the `function` by adding [`has_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/has_category) like so:

   ```
   function addBadge2Title($title)
   {
       // return the $title unmodified if the post does not have the category
       if(!has_category('badge-category'))
           return $title;

       // add the badge
       $seconds = strtotime("now") - strtotime(get_the_date("Y/m/d"));
       $badge = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/images/new_ribbon.gif';
       if ($seconds < 10950400) {
           $title = '<img class="new_ribbon" width="75"  height="75" src="' . $badge . '" >' . $title;
       }
       return $title;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this @Aifrim but this applies all the titles across the site's posts and pages. I want to apply this to a specific category of blog post. Can we add a filer or condition to a specific blog category? thanks in advance for your time though

Comment: @kalyan: I added the new code that fits your needs.